# Use django admin's readonly_fields with a FileField

Tags: django, django-admin

When using the new `readonly_fields` attribute of the django `ModelAdmin` class, I found that if I put the name of a field that's defined as a `FileField` in the `readonly_fields`, it doesn't show a working link, it just shows the relative path. I'd like a downloadable link.

Comment: Here is the related [`ticket`](http://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/14497) for your problem. Doesn't look like there's a patch yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While the `Django Admin` issue is still not fixed,

I use this widget as a poor man's solution to the problem above:

```
#your_app/models.py
class ModelWithFileField(models.Model):
    ...
    file = models.FileField(upload_to='dir/')

#your_app/admin.py

import os

from django import forms
from django.utils.encoding import force_unicode
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe
from django.utils.html import escape

class ReadonlyFileInput(forms.Widget):
    def __init__(self, obj, attrs=None):
        self.object = obj
        super(ReadonlyFileInput, self).__init__(attrs)
    def render(self, name, value, attrs=None):
        if value and hasattr(value, "url"):
            return mark_safe(u'<p><a href="%s">%s</a></p>'\
            % (escape(value.url),\
            escape(force_unicode(os.path.basename(value.path)))))
        else:
            return ''

class ModelWithFileFieldForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = ModelWithFileField       

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ModelWithFileFieldForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['file'].widget = ReadonlyFileInput(self.instance)

   # If you are paranoid enough, you can override the clean() method as well, 
   # to be sure that no one has been messing with your beloved file by
   # maliciously manipulating the POST data. If you don't expect compete
   # strangers to be using your admin site, this is not an issue.

class ModelWithFileFieldAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin)
    form = ModelWithFileFieldForm
    ...
    def get_readonly_fields(self, request, obj=None):
        return [...] #The 'file' field should not be present in this list
```